# CSS Maintain Aspect Ratio not working

Tags: css, responsive-design, responsive, aspect-ratio, browser-bugs

This is the strangest thing, I have used this method many times before but it seems to be breaking for me now.

Here is a duplicate question that provides this method as an answer:

[Maintain the aspect ratio of a div with CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1495407/maintain-the-aspect-ratio-of-a-div-with-css#)

But for some unknown reason it's breaking for me in Firefox and Chrome. From what I can gather it's calculating the padding according to the parent of the element I'm applying the style to...

In this case it's not looking at `.test` but instead is looking at `.parent` to calculate the padding:

```css
.parent {
  width: 200px;
}

.test {
  width: 50px;
  background: red;
  padding-top: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class='parent'>
  <div class='test'></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I have confirmed with friends that they also see a tall rectangle instead of a square... which makes no sense

Comment: It's calculated as percentage of the parent, as always has been. In the answer that you link, the element has a width of 100%, so that the width of the child is the same than the width of the parent

Comment: D'oh! Blonde moment.. nothing to see here move along folks :D

Comment: Try `padding-top: 25%;`

Comment: @RickSibley no, I believe the previous comment is correct. You are meant to make the child 100% width and control the sizing with the parent.

I will post an answer with the correct implementation now

Comment: So you are changing `.test {width: 50px;}` to `.test {width: 100%}`? What were you trying to achieve with the 50px?

Comment: @RickSibley I only put the .test div inside a .parent for the purpose of this question to prove that it was looking at the parent... I thought that was incorrect behaviour. I thought it was meant to get it's padding value from .test and should have given me a square. Sorry for causing confusion. It was a brain-fart on my behalf.

Comment: Seemed like you were asking for something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/MpXYr/5128/ ; but I might have just misunderstood.

Comment: Ah right, that is actually a cool method you have there, but not what I was asking. Apologies.

Comment: All good, glad you got the answer you needed. Happy coding!

Answer (score 5):

CSS has a property for this

```css
.square {
  aspect-ratio: 1 / 1;
  width: 100px;
  background: grey;
  padding: 10px;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="square">a sqaure</div>
```

**update:**
there is another way if your support is absolutely crucial and you cant live with firefox being unsupported then here you go. But its a bit janky.

```css
div {
width: 5em;
height: 5em;
font-size: 3vw; background: grey; padding: 0.5em;}

/*em is relative to font-size so you could use that and vw is veiwport width where 100 is all of the veiwport. the size of the shape is now 5 * 3vh*/
```

```html
<div>hello</div>
```

Comment: What's the point to use `aspect-ratio` prop since it doesn't have support in all major browsers?

Comment: doesn't `aspect ratio` make code more readable instead of hacks

Comment: now it doesn't. still have to use hacks due to it's support

Comment: to be fare firefox doenst support aspect-ratio when I thought it did but I wouldnt care inless my site is oriented at that market.

Comment: such approach takes place if you have 1 potential user on your website

Answer (score 2):

That is actually the correct behaviour. You are meant to make the child 100% width and control the sizing with the parent.

Example:

```css
.parent {
  width: 200px;
}

.child {
  width: 100%;
  background: red;
  padding-top: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

Here is a nice method proposed on CSS-Tricks that helps you get the correct padding you need for the desired ratio:

**Aspect Ratio - 2:1**

```css
.parent {
  width: 200px;
}

.child {
  width: 100%;
  background: red;
  padding-top: calc(1 / 2 * 100%); // will give you an aspect ratio of 2:1
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

**Aspect Ratio - 3:1**

```css
.parent {
  width: 200px;
}

.child {
  width: 100%;
  background: red;
  padding-top: calc(1 / 3 * 100%); // will give you an aspect ratio of 3:1
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

**Aspect Ratio - 16:9**

```css
.parent {
  width: 200px;
}

.child {
  width: 100%;
  background: red;
  padding-top: calc(9 / 16 * 100%); // will give you an aspect ratio of 16:9
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

You can find the full article here:
https://css-tricks.com/aspect-ratio-boxes/